# A 3rd party application reads my asset folder

Tags: android, security, permissions

A 3rd party security application reads into my application. They probably read my asset folder.

How is this possible? I thought that the sandbox model prevented from external access to the internal data structure of an app?

I've checked their permission. They are using: access_coarse_location, access_fine_location, access_network_state, change_network_state, internet, kill_background_processes, modify_audio_settings, manage_device_admins, wake_lock, read_sms, receive_sms, write_secure_settings, flashlight, vibrate, disable_keyguard, get_accounts, camera, read_phone_state, get_tasks, receive_boot_completed,  read_external_storage, read_call_logs, write_call_logs, write_external_storage, write_media_storage, access_wifi_state, change_wifi_state

What are manage_device_admins and write_media?

I thought that write_secure_settings and write_media_storage were reserved for android?

Here are the permissions I am using:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS" />
```

Is there any issues associated with android:allowBackup="true"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They probably read my asset folder.

Sure. Other apps read other things out of your APK. For example, the home screen reads your icon and label for your launcher activity.

> How is this possible?

The contents of your APK are world-readable. This includes `assets/` and `res/`.

> I thought that the sandbox model prevented from external access to the internal data structure of an app?

Android protects files created on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Those may hold private information for the user. Android does not protect the APK itself from inspection.